# Python Text Field in Maya

Tags: python, text, textfield, maya

I was wondering how I would be able to go about getting the text in a textfield to be passed into the Focus Distance attribute of a camera in Maya?

I've been working on it so far and the method I have setup is that a command will be run when enter is hit within the textfield, from there is finds the selected camera and tries to query the text inside of the textfield.

```
cmds.textField("focusdistance", parent="Extra", enterCommand=focusdistance)
```

Once you hit enter it will run:

```
def focusdistance(self):
    fd = cmds.ls(sl=True)[0]
    cmds.setAttr('query="focusdistacne.tx"')
```

I've got it up and running, but I also keep getting and error from Maya:

```
# Error: RuntimeError: file <maya console> line 85: setAttr: Invalid object name: query="focusdistacne.tx" #
```

So to simplify. I have a textfield that is editable and can run a command when enter is hit. When enter is hit I would like for the numbers entered in the textfield to be passed into the focus distance attribute of a selected camera in Maya.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you made any headway?

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake yeah I fixed it and got it all up and running. In the end I did this.

    `focusdistancefield = cmds.floatField("focusdistance", enterCommand=focusdistance)`

`def focusdistance(self):
        fd = cmds.ls(sl=True)[0]
        value = cmds.floatField(focusdistancefield, query = True, value = True)
        cmds.setAttr(fd + ".focusDistance", value)`

And I can't make this look pretty, whoops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This format won't work:

```
cmds.setAttr('query="focusdistacne.tx"')
```

And default maya camera's don't have a `focusdistance` attribute -- there's `centerOfInterest` which is the target that the camera orbits around, and `focalLength` which affects FOV. I'm going to keep `focusdistance` below on the assumption that you're working with some kind of special camera, but you should check the [maya docs](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya/files/GUID-C3EBB008-7DBE-4B9D-B9AC-1DA974CEFE15-htm.html) the make sure you've got the right setting

You need to save the name of the textfield you've created so the `focusdistance` function can ask it questions.  You also need to fix that `setAttr`.  I think you're looking for something like this:

```
# in the part of the class where you create the textfield:

self.focal_dist_field = cmds.textField("focusdistance", parent="Extra", enterCommand=self.focusdistance)
```

and, when you've got the textField, you'll probably have to convert its contents to a number to be able to set them on a numeric attribute (unless your `focusDistance` attribute is a string?)

```
def focusdistance(self):
   target = cmds.ls(sl=True)[0]
   # get the text, or a '0' if there's nothing entered
   value = cmds.textField(self. focal_dist_field, q=True, text=True) or "0"

   # convert the text to a number if possible
   # in practice you probably want a FloatField control
   # instead of a TextField so you can skip this
   try:   
       numeric_value = float(value)
   except ValueError: 
       numeric_value = 0
   cmds.setAttr(target + ".focusdistance", numeric_value)
```

Comment: Hello,

I had the feeling that format wouldn't work which is why I came here.

I went and triple checked the Maya docs/ Python Commands/ Maya itself and there is a `focusDistance` attribute that can be manipulated, but the argument type is linear as well.

I went around and messed with what you mentioned and it all ended up working well; thank you for that! I did swap out the `textField` for a `floatField` and that helped shorten up everything. The only reason I wasn't using one earlier is because I didn't know they exist. In the end my code looked like:

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo in the `focusdistance` function: `query='focusdistacne'`

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I went through and fixed that, but i'm still getting an error. Anything else you think I could do to fix it?

`# Error: RuntimeError: file <maya console> line 85: setAttr: Invalid object name: query="focusdistance.tx" #`

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `setAttr`?

Comment: By the way, when you have several words in a single variable, we often distinguish them by capitalising all but the first: `focusDistance`.

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake Not true in Python. Pep8 calls for words to all be lowercase separated by underscores.

Comment: @JoshKopen It *is* true in Python that people *often* use camelCase, whatever Pep8 says. I certainly do, and judging by a few examples I found, so does Maya. But let's see what the OP says.

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake Although there is obviously nothing stopping you from doing camelcase, I wouldn't suggest to someone to use it when it's not the accepted standard. Obviously people do this just like many other inconsistencies people do when it comes to stylization, I just am correcting that you are advocating for it when it's definitely not the preferred method.

Comment: I'm not *advocating* anything in this case (although I personally prefer camseCase to underscores). I'm suggesting that Maya might care about the difference between `focusDistance` and `focusdistance`. I don't know whether that's the issue, though, which is why I said "let's see what the OP says".

Comment: IMO it's more important to keep to the conventions of a framework than ones of the language. Consistency is more important than the actual choice of the convention, after all.